# Memory usage on MQTT subscription

Tags: mqtt, iot, messagebroker

How much of memory used whenever we use from **# (wildcard)** to subscription into many topics? for example if we have over **10M topics**, it's possible to use **#** to subscribe into all of them, or it caused to memory leaks?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is strictly related to the MQTT broker and client implementation. 
Of course, the MQTT standard specification doesn't provide any information on the features related to such implementation.

Paolo.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on ppatierno's answer.

For most well designed brokers the number or scope (for wild card) subscriptions shouldn't really change the amount of memory used under normal circumstances . At most the storage should equate to the topic string that the client subscribes to, this will be matched against a incoming message to see if it should be delivered.

Where this may not hold true is with persistent subscriptions (where the clean session value is not set to true). In this case if a client disconnects then messages may be queued until it reconnects. The amount of memory consumed here will be a function of the number of messages and their size (plus what discard policy the broker may have) and not directly a function of the number of subscribed topics.

To answer the second part of your question, subscribing to 10,000,000 topics using the wildcard is not likely to cause a memory leak, but it may very well flood the client depending on how often messages are published on those topics.